# Mongoose model name as variable

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is there a way to create a collection via a variable model name? I tried this:

```
app.post("/post", function(req, res){
if(req.body.post.group =="Sunnah") {
    var group1 = req.body.post.group;
    group1.create(req.body.post, function(err, newSunnah){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/view");
        }
    });
} if(req.body.post.group !=="Sunnah") {
    res.send("Not available");
}
});
```

But it return "TypeError: group1.create is not a function".

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use the Mongoose model and not its name. You can retrieve the model with `mongoose.model(group1)` and, with it, you can use `create`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the Mongoose model and not its name. You can retrieve the model with `mongoose.model(group1)` and, with it, you can use `create`.

Assuming you have already created your models with their respective schemas, you could do the following:

```
    var group1 = req.body.post.group;
    var groupModel = mongoose.model(group1);

    groupModel.create(req.body.post, function(err, newSunnah){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/view");
        }
    });
```

Comment: can we query the same way, using find instead of create?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Mongoose ODM documentation about [models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). `group1` is not just a collection or model name, Its an actual Model responsible for creating and reading documents from the underlying MongoDB database. So, It will be like

```
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', <-YOUR-SCHEAMA->);
Model.create({}, function(error, doc) {
  ....
});
```

So, What the possible way that you can do is to store your model in array and just pass your array name dynamically.

```
var models = [];
models['Sunnah'] = mongoose.model('Sunnah', <-YOUR-SCHEAMA->);
models['XYZ'] = mongoose.model('XYZ', <-YOUR-SCHEAMA->);

app.post("/post", function(req, res){
  ...
  models[group1].create(req.body.post, function(err, newSunnah){
    ....
  });
  ...
});
```

Comment: There is no need to keep track of the models in an array as `mongoose.model(modelName)` does the trick. Also, shouldn't your `models` variable be an object? It'll work but it is strange to set properties in arrays other than indexes.

Comment: Using `mongoose.model(modelName)` will create a model every-time on request. And also the index will not set on the beginning on the app start.

Comment: Storing the model in `Variable` and `Array/Object` make difference ?

Comment: Mongoose only create models when you call `mongoose.model(NAME, SCHEMA)`. When you call it only with the name, it retrieves the model with that name ( https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model ) . About whether to store it in an array or object, the code will work both ways but I would argue it is more readable if you use object.